# Visualizing a CUP grammar

Tags: compiler, grammar, visualization

I am implementing a grammar in [CUP](http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/), and it would often be helpful to see everything at a glance. This could also be useful in finding errors quickly.

Are there any programs out there that will visualize grammar in the CUP syntax? Or can you think of a very easy way of doing it (for instance, convert the grammar to another format that program X can read).

Comment: Some warning on the bright yellow would be nice... My eyes hurt...

Comment: @YannisRizos Just be happy there aren't flashing rainbow GIFs.

Comment: ANTLR has excellent visualisation, at least of parse trees. (I don't recall if you can visualise the grammar itself). I've never heard of CUP, so I don't know if there's some reason to prefer it, or indeed if the two are interchangeable.

Comment: last updated 2009?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to convert it to another format first.

You could generate a graph of the grammar by using a combination of [ANTLRWorks](http://www.antlr.org/works/) and [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

Someone did something similar here to generate [graphs for the Ruby, JavaScript, and Java 1.5 grammars](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2006/10/27/visualization-of-rubys-grammar).